# How to build a simple Java Rest API service with dependency injection

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection

I don't want to use Spring.

Here is the tach stack I found so far:

- Gradle
- Gretty
- Jersey
- Guice

I can't manage to make Guice work with Gretty.
Following https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule, I have:

```java
public class GuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                serve("/api/v1/*").with(MyResource.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, MyResource is not a servlet:

```java
@Path("hello-world")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response helloWorld() {
        return Response.ok("hello world").build();
    }
}
```

Is there a more appropriate stack to achieve my goal?
Am I missing something in my code?